# In VS2012 how to Browse With IE in private mode

Tags: visual-studio-2012, internet-explorer-10

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and when building an ASP.NET MVC4 application I'm able to set the "Browse With" to an internet browser (Immulator/Simulator) of my choosing. For example: Google Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, etc..

Instead of just using the default Internet Explorer I wanted to use Internet Explorer In-Private Mode.

I've tried:

[image]

and

[image]

It will work the first time but then every subsequent try after that results back to IE in normal mode.

I am able to accomplish this with Chrome in Incognito mode easily. But for some reason it's not working for IE.  I'm using IE10.

Is anyone else able to do this successfully?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually have to use the 32-bit version of Internet Exploring for debugging in Visual Studio 2012.  So, if you add a browser with the following path:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"

and then use the -private argument, it will work correctly.

-Shaun

Comment: kinda late to the party but is this also works with chrome. The argument would simply be -incognito